# Example of mobile app sign up with Facebook/Twitter and email

Tags: android, ios, facebook, authentication, twitter

I need to develop a typical app that allows users to sign up via Facebook/Twitter or email/password.

I have been searching but found no direct solutions. Most pointed to old 3rd party framework or simply Facebook/twitter sdk which doesn't really help.

This app will need to be available to iOS and android. Logins should be persistent. And also, I would prefer to use social framework for iOS rather than Facebook sdk.

Appreciate if someone who has experience with this provide some examples or the sequence flow when a user signs up.

Comment: Twitter takes a little more work on Android since it lacks a native sdk, but for Facebook authentication, I think using the SDK is the easiest solution. Is there a particular reason you are avoiding it?

Comment: Cause social framework is easier to work with and switching between Facebook and Twitter doesn't take drastic changes. I notice whenever I ask advice for design problems someone will vote it down or vote to close. What's wrong with such questions?